# Why is ww[[1]] not a valid variable in FindMinValue and Plot

Tags: functions, variable

Why is `ww[[1]]` not a valid variable when given to `FindMinValue` and `Plot`, but is a variable in `Minimize`? How can I fix the problem?

```
In:
ww = Table[w[i], {i, 1, 6}];
a1[y1_, x_] = Function[#1*Cos[#1*0.1] + #2*2][y1, x];

Minimize[a1[ww[[1]], 3], ww[[1]]]
FindMinValue[a1[ww[[1]], 3], {ww[[1]], 1}]
Plot[a1[ww[[1]], 3], {ww[[1]], 0, 1}]

Out:
{0.389037, {w[1] -> -8.60334}}

FindMinValue::vloc: The variable ww[[1]] cannot be localized so that it can 
be assigned to numerical values. >>

FindMinValue[a1[ww[[1]], 3], {ww[[1]], 1}]

Plot::write: Tag Part in ww[[1]] is Protected. >>

Plot[a1[ww[[1]], 3], {ww[[1]], 0, 1}]
```

Comment: `Plot` has the attribute `HoldAll`, but you may enforce evaluation with `Evaluate`: `Plot[Evaluate[a1[ww[[1]], 3]], Evaluate[{ww[[1]], 0, 1}]]`. Similarly, you may use `FindMinValue[a1[ww[[1]], 3], Evaluate@{ww[[1]], 1}]`.

Comment: Thanks a lots. But it is not uncomfortable to use "Evaluate" all time. Maybe is there other way how make function with different amount of variables defined by array ?

Answer (score 1):

This is not so much an answer as some advice on how you can avoid all the issues that are causing you problems by getting rid of unnecessary complications in your code. You will do better by abandoning the array `ww` and `Function`.

```
a1[y_, x_] := y Cos[.1 y] + 2 x
min = Minimize[a1[w[1], 3], w[1]]
```

> `{0.389037, {w[1] -> -8.60334}}`

```
FindMinValue[a1[w[1], 3], {w[1], -1}]
```

> `0.389037`

To make a plot showing the minimum, extract the coordinates of the minimum

```
minPt = {min[[2, 1, 2]], min[[1]]}
```

> `{-8.60334, 0.389037}`

and add it to a plot of `a` with `Epilog`.

```
Plot[a1[w[1], 3], {w[1], -15, 1},
  Epilog -> {Red, AbsolutePointSize[5], Point[minPt]}]
```

[image: plot]

Comment: Thanks. But my general goal is to learn how make function with different amount of variables defined by array (Table).

Comment: @ILIa. In general you don't have make indexed variables with `Table`, you can just refer to as I did in the code above and there will be automatically created. If for some strange reason you really do have make them, `Do` is better than `Table`